# CRON is running twice in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, cron

In nodejs I have scheduled a CRON that is running every day at 10 AM to send the push notification.
Now the issue is, every time when this CRON is triggering 2 notifications are being sent to the user's device.  Here is my code

`var job2 = new CronJob('00 00 10 * * *', (res) => { woStatusCheck(); }, null, true, 'Asia/Kolkata'); job2.start();`

Answer (score 1):

You can check their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron). 4th parameter of the constructor is named `start` and by sending `true` for it, it will run the job before exiting the constructor. Then calling your `job.start()` runs it again. You either send `false` at 4th parameter and use the `.start()` or remove the `.start()` and send `true`

Comment: Hi. The solution you suggest was working fine on the localhost. But once I deployed it on AWS it behave same as still the cron is executing twice

Comment: Here is my code  var job2 = new CronJob('00 00 10 * * *', async(res) => {
   await woStatusCheck();
}, null, false, 'Asia/Kolkata');
job2.start();

Comment: have you restarted the server to make sure it applies the changes?

Comment: Yes, I restarted server, but still no luck . Every single cron is running twice on the server

Comment: @NareshKukreti I am noticing the same behaviour you were experiencing in AWS EC2 instance. Did you have any luck fixing this?